# Turing Machine for regular languages

Tags: regular-language, reduction, turing-machines, decidable, undecidable-instances

Theorem 5.3 from Sipser's TOC book is about decidability of Regular_TM = {M | M is a Turing Machines (TMs) and L(M) is regular languages}. For the sake of reaching a contradiction, TM R is assumed to be a decider for Regular_TM and then R is used to decide Acceptance problem as shown in the blow TM S:

`S = "On input (M,w) where M is a TM and w is a string: 
1. Construct the code of TM M2 as follows: 
     M2 = "On input x:
         (a) If x of the form 0^n1^n, accept.
         (b) else, run M on w and if M accepts w, then accept."
2. Run R on (M2).
3. If R accepts, accept; if R rejects, reject."`

I have two questions. The first is x in M_2 fixed? if not, where does it come from ?

The 2nd question. Why do we care about x in M2. If R is truly a decider, why do we care about check if x is in 0^n1^n. So does a TM S' below works?

`S = "On input (M,w) where M is a TM and w is a string: 
1. Construct the code of TM M2 as follows: 
     M2 = "On input x: //ignore x
         (a) run M on w and if M accepts w, then accept else reject."
2. Run R on (M2).
3. If R accepts, accept; if R rejects, reject."`

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550647/undecidability-of-regular-tm

Comment: Have you read the Proof Idea preceding the details you have posted? It should answer your questions. x is not fixed, actually it does not even appear explicitely, just as the potential input to the TM M2 that is constructed but never simulated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its is about CS theory not programming.